# Arithmetic operations using Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to perform an arithmetic operation using Criteria API in hibernate. The SQL is:

```
SELECT salary + 500 FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

How to achieve this using Criteria?

I am able to retrieve only the SALARY column using `Projection` but after that not sure how to perform the arithmetic operation on that:
    session.createCriteria(Employee.class).setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("salary"))

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

You have several possibilitiies:

- create your own Projection class, which generates the "salary + 500" select clause. You can use the property projection as a template
- use HQL rather than Criteria
- not doing this in the query, but doing it in Java: you select the salary, ietarate through the returned list, and add 500 to every salary in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the immidiate response. Can you please provide some sample code like how to create our own Projection class?

Comment: @user182944 Don't overkill. Best approach is getting the value with HQL and then add 500 IMHO.

Comment: Using HQL, we can directly use the `+` operator inside query rather than adding 500 after fetching the values. But still I want to create my own Projection class since I am asked to use criteria only for my app(really frustrated but can't help it :( ). The first step of doing this might be implementing the Projection interface but don't know what to do with the unimplemented methods of that Projection Interface to fulfill my purpose. Can someone please guide?

Comment: As I said, use the property projection as a starting point: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/criterion/PropertyProjection.java

Answer (score 1):

See the example below, which uses SQL Projections for finding the product between price and quantity.

```
session.createCriteria(Order.class) 
        .createAlias("order", "od") 
        .setProjection( Projections.projectionList() 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("od.orderId") ) 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("od.rate") ) 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("od.quantity") ) 
            .add( Projections.sqlProjection( 
                    "price * quantity as total", 
                    new String[] { "totalAmount" }, 
                    new Type[] { Hibernate.DOUBLE } 
                  ) 
            ) 
        );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the above code, I think both the `total` and `totalAmount` would be the same name i.e. either both `total` or both `totalAmount`. When I try with different names, I am getting an exception.